# ignore_case doesn't work for elastic search stop token filter

Tags: elasticsearch, stop-words, ignore-case

I'm trying to test stop token filter that does stop words case sensitively. I try the example from elastic searche's documentation as is. But it doesn't work. Is the documentation wrong or I'm doing something wrong.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html

```
PUT /my-index-000001
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [ "my_custom_stop_words_filter" ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_custom_stop_words_filter": {
          "type": "stop",
          "ignore_case": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I do

```
GET my-index-000001/_analyze
{
  "field": "ASCII_FIELD", 
  "text" :"this that a b The is IS was açaí à la carte"
}
```

I wouldn't expect either "The" or "IS" as one of the tokens. However they are present. It seems to remove the lower case stop words
I add a document like this

```
PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1
{    
  "ASCII_FIELD" :"this that a b The is IS was  açaí à la carte"
}
```

I search like below and I shouldn't have gotten a hit, but I get the results back

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "ASCII_FIELD": "The"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your term have "The" look the documentation.

Documentation:

> When not customized, the filter removes the following English stop
> words by default:
>
> a, an, and, are, as, at, be, but, by, for, if, in, into, is, it, no,
> not, of, on, or, such, that, the, their, then, there, these, they,
> this, to, was, will, with

You have two option:

Add filter lowercase:

```
 "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_custom_stop_words_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
```

OR

Add in your filter "stopwords": "*english*",

```
  "my_custom_stop_words_filter": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_",
          "ignore_case": true
        }
```

Test:

```
GET my-index-000001/_analyze
{
  "field": "ASCII_FIELD", 
  "text" :"this that a b The is IS was açaí à la carte"
}
```

Tokens:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "b",
      "start_offset": 12,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "açaí",
      "start_offset": 28,
      "end_offset": 32,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 8
    },
    {
      "token": "à",
      "start_offset": 33,
      "end_offset": 34,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 9
    },
    {
      "token": "la",
      "start_offset": 35,
      "end_offset": 37,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 10
    },
    {
      "token": "carte",
      "start_offset": 38,
      "end_offset": 43,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 11
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works for me to add the lowercase as we don't have issues converting our texts converted to lowercase. However, I wonder what would be the solution if we can't convert to lowercase or we have non-english chars.

Comment: You can pass the list stopwords manually.